# Nissan Primera P11-144: electro «control box»?

Tags: nissan, electronics, primera

On my car, *Nissan Primera P11-144,* there is a couple of electrical malfunctions on secondary systems, namely on climate control and ceiling lighting: CC blows only hot air regardless of set temperature, while CL doesn’t react to door closure / engine start and has to be switched manually. The car is working perfectly fine otherwise, including no dash board errors.

Several people (whom i can’t get in touch with) have at different times independently mentioned that the car’s electro «control box», driving both of these functions, can be the issue and has to be replaced – something which supposedly isn’t uncommon on this car model.

What can this unit be? To try to find a replacement i would need its full name / part number.